# 2.8 Can't find "Create orientation" in the menus, therefore can't add it to "Add to quick favorites" does not work in Search

Tags: interface, workflow, shortcut, quick-favorites

Search says "create orientation" is in Transform menu, but it's not there.
Where is it ?

I did map my own key combination for it, but still.
The one from 2.79 ,   Ctrl+Alt+Space

Would be much easier if anything could be added to quick favourites directly from Search, to streamline the processes even more.

["Add to quick favorites" does not work in Search](https://developer.blender.org/T59661)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you're looking for? You can right click to create a shortcut:

[image]

Comment: Yes it is, thanks !

Comment: Stack doesn't let me accept an answer this soon.